# Convert AMF request to XML?

Tags: xml, amf

I am able to see amf requests when using LoadUIWeb.  Is there a way to covert the AMF requests to xml format?  I want to use with soapUI

Answer (score 0):

Because LoadUIWeb records TCP traffic, there is no direct way to convert it to a SoapUI test case.

I would recommend you build your tests against them directly in SoapUI, then load test them with LoadUI.

Please feel free to reach out to SmartBear [product support](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=LoadUIWebPro) or [contact a sales rep](http://smartbear.com/contact-us/) to get pre-sales support.